# Envio de correo con PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente codigo en Java para enviar correo electronico

```
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", user);
   props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
   htmlBody = Disenio(tercero, titulo, mensaje);
   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mailDestino));
   message.setSubject(titulo); //adjuntar asunto...
   message.setContent( htmlBody, "text/html");
   Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
   t.connect(user, pass);
   t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
   t.close();
```

Tengo en siguien codigo en php para enviar el correo

```
        $mail=new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPOptions  = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );            
        $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
        $mail->Host=$host;
        $mail->Username=$user;
        $mail->Password=$pass;
        $mail->SMTPSecure= 'tls';                            
        $mail->Port= 25; 

        $mail->AddAddress($mailDestino);
        $mail->Subject = $titulo;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body=$this->Disenio($tercero,$titulo,$mensaje);
        $mail->AltBody=$mensaje;
        $mail->setLanguage('es');
        if($mail->send()){
            $result="OK";
        }else{
            $result="Mail Error".$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

Utilizo el mismo host, usuario y password en ambos, en Java me FUNCIONA pero en Php NO, me sale el siguiente error:

> Mail ErrorError SMTP: Los siguientes destinos fallaron: xxxxx@gmail.com: Verification failed for 
>   Unrouteable address
>   Sender verify failed

Leyendo en internet he leido que el error se debe a un problema con el servidor de correo por alguna configuracion o algo, pero si asi fuera el Java tampoco me deberia funcionar por eso he querido colocar la comparación de los dos lenguajes, se que son dos lenguajes diferentes pero no creo que sea por el servidor de correo por que en java me funciona perfectamente

Comment: Estas seguro que el puerto 25 es el que usa tu servidor, por lo visto quieres usar tls como seguridad pero por lo general los puertos son distintos al puerto 25 que es inseguro,  por ejemplo en los servidores smtp  seguros de google el puerto ssl es el 465 y el tls es 587, comprueba esta configuracion

Comment: Ya he intentado con todos los puertos y sigue saliendo el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, lo que dice @juanpinzon es cierto, debieras usar el puerto 587. Pero supongamos que das con el puerto correcto.

En tu código java no estás comprobando un envío exitoso de tu correo. Simplemente ejecutas el envío y cierras. El equivalente en PHP, en vez de

```
if($mail->send()){
    $result="OK";
}else{
    $result="Mail Error".$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Sería simplemente hacer

```
$mail->send();
```

En segundo lugar, dices que en java funciona pero ¿Comprobaste que el destinatario recibió el correo?

Yo lo que veo es que el error que figura en tu pregunta equivale a un header 550. Y ese error se produce no por culpa del cliente (tú) sino por culpa del servidor (ellos), por dos causas posibles:  la dirección de correo no existe, o el servidor está haciendo Sender Verify.

En el segundo caso, significa que si tu proveedor de correo no está en su lista blanca, no va a dejar entrar el mensaje. Eso no puedes arreglarlo de tu lado más que pasando por un SMTP oficial como Amazon SES, SendGrid, Mailchimp, etc.

Hay [un thread con un caso parecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288254/smtp-error-the-following-recipients-failedxxxx) en StackOverflow (no este sino el de al lado) pero en realidad no ofrece soluciones más que encender el modo debug.

Comment: En java si llega al correo del destinatario, el mensaje llega perfectamente al correo donde debe, pero si es java deja no se por que deberia molestar con PhpMailer

Comment: Bueno, en el thread que dejé linkeado, a un usuario le funcionó comentando la instrucción `$mail->isSMTP()` pero no tiene pies ni cabeza

Comment: Parecio que funciono comentando la instrucción $mail->isSMTP() ya que entra 
 if($mail->send()){
    $result="OK";
}, y responde OK, Sin embargo aun no me llega el correo destinatario